# Run a batch file on exiting specific program

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I want a batch file to run when I exit a specific program, Nokia Suite in my case.
I want to use Windows 7 task scheduler and would prefer avoiding any 3rd party program.

I have already checked Application event log and Nokia Suite seems to generate only one event with event ID 1.

Is it possible to achieve this using windows task scheduler?

Comment: It's possible if you start Nokia with a batch file, then kick off the next step after it runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just write a batch file that starts the application then does what you want it to do after. This way the batch processing pauses while your Nokia stuff is running, then when it quits, goes on to the next line. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx. For help on batch files see http://commandwindows.com/batch.htm.

Comment: nice idea..
will still wait for some better idea though..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it seems like it should work.

Open the Task Scheduler & Create a Task

On the Triggers Tab, press "New.." and Set
 Begin the task: On an Event
 Log : Application
 Source: Application
 Event ID: 1

On the Actions Tab, press "New.." and Set
 Action: Start a program
 Program/Script: yada.bat
  (or possibly:  cmd /c yada.bat)
  etc.